# $1$ has infinitely many representation as a sum of three cubes

Tags: number-theory

I am working on the following exercise:

> Prove that $1$ has infinitely many representations as a sum of three cubes. (The cubes can be negative.)

As a hint the identity 
$$(9m^4)^3+(3mn^3-9m^4)^3+(n^4-9m^3n)^3 = n^{12}$$

is mentioned. But I do not see how to continue from there. Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Set $n=1$ and $m$ arbitrary.

**Alternate solution**

$$1=1^3+m^3+(-m)^3$$

Comment: Ah ok, that was easier than I expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @3nondatur Check the alternate solution, I think it is even easier.